OAuth2 Consent Screen Shows Domain Instead of App Name and Logo in Testing Environment for YouTube Data API v3
I am making use of YouTube Data API v3 for my project. I am running the application in the testing Environment During Auth2.0 Process it is showing up the domain instead of the App Name on consenst screen, login screen. Also the App logo is not showing up during Testing Environment.
I have looked into the app is created and all configuration is correct as required but I am still facing the same problem.

please show your consent screen configuration and your code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
